# Areas and adaptive-step Runge-Kutta methods

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I have been using standard, non-adaptive symplectic integrators in my work for many years. This kind of integrator requires the user to provide a time-step $\Delta t$, which is kept fixed during propagation, such that the number of iterations is given by $t_f/\Delta t$, where $t_f$ is the desired final time. On the other hand, in adaptive-step Runge-Kutta methods the step-size is tuned throughout integration, becoming smaller *e.g* near singularities and larger in continuous terrain.

The number of iterations required by an explicit adaptive-step method such as [Dormand and Prince's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormand%E2%80%93Prince_method), when compared to a 6th order symplectic integrator such as [Blanes and Moan's](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042701004927), is thousands of times smaller in my applications. The energy drift is minuscule and essentially negligible in my case, as I'm only interested in moderate-time dynamics. However, I have to code all my integrators by hand, because I need to compute not only the trajectories but also several objects that need to be calculated at run time. One of them is the area encircled by the trajectory and the straight line connecting its initial and final points. Unfortunately, because of the big jumps in the adaptive-step propagation, my area comes out terrible: While my points and energies have a relative error of $\mathcal{O}(10^{-10})$, my areas are $\mathcal{O}(10^{-2})$. Since this area is really *the* most important quantity in my work, this completely prohibits me of using adaptive steps, rendering me *very sad indeed*.

While taking a look to see why I could get near-machine precision in points and energies but not in areas, I noticed this is because the intermediate steps used in my adaptive-step algorithm go completely nuts: The final point makes sense, but all the intermediate ones are just crazy. I am not an expert in Runge-Kutta methods, so I don't know the correct terminology, but **is there an adaptive-step algorithm that has well-behaved enough intermediate steps to provide me with an area that has the same accuracy as my trajectories?**

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "intermediate steps." In Runge-Kutta you estimate the state of the system after one timestep. Then you may do it again for another timestep. If the state at the end of the first timestep doesn't make sense, the method is inaccurate. In the meantime you will have computed a bunch of system states that are not on the trajectory. Which states are the "crazy" ones?

Comment: You could try to find a differential equation for the area and add this as a component to the ODE system. You could do what the `Refine` option in the Matlab solvers does and interpolate using the "dense output" polynomials. Matlab by default adds 3 points per segment (`Refine=4`), the jula-lang diffeq solvers have a default of 10 segments per integration step. Then use these interpolated points to get a better area approximation.

Comment: @DavidK The final point in adaptive RK is given by $x_f = x_i + \sum_i b_i k_i$. The intermediate steps I'm talking about are each $b_i k_i$. These steps are not at all well-behaved.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Unfortunately this sounds extremely expensive. In practice I solve the equations of motion for non-interacting gases with around 10 million particles. It is mandatory that each full RK step takes less than 20 nanoseconds. I looked around and it might be that RK algorithms with completely positive Butcher tableaus have more well-behaved $k$s, but I just tried it and the error in the area is still disproportional when compared to the error in the trajectories =(

Comment: You're supposed to throw away the $b_ik_i$ data in the end. That's what makes them "intermediate steps".

Comment: @DavidK Yes. I was trying to use them to try to solve the problem, but it didn't work. If I use only the final point the step-size can be so large I'm essentially approximating a circle by a secant.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to interpolate the velocities between two "final" states so that you get something like a circular arc or perhaps a parabolic arc. Or take a second look at Lutz Lehmann's suggestions. In particular, if area is part of the equations then I'd expect the result of a step to be more like an integration along the curve and not just the area of a triangle formed by a secant.